# run my method when redux change store props. ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a specific problem In my React-Redux app. I use Redux-saga to communication with REST API, and so Redux-saga doesn't return a promise.

In my application I also use state (in addition to the store) that I would like to change my state after receiving the SUCCESS response from Redux-saga.

My method `this.props.handleLastWeek(this.props.dateFrom, this.props.dateTo)` returns: this.props.isLoading: false and this.props.dataApi when redux-saga is success.

SO I would like to run method `appendTable()` when `this.props.handleLastWeek` returns this.props.isLoading false and this.props.dataApi is not null.

PS: is purecomponent not a problem?

My code looks something like this:

```
class TableComponent extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      ...
    };

    this.handleDateWeek = this.handleDateWeek.bind(this);
    this.appendTable = this.appendTable.bind(this);
  }

   componentDidMount() {
     this.handleDateWeek();
   }

  handleDateWeek() {
    this.props.handleLastWeek(this.props.dateFrom, this.props.dateTo);
  }

  appendTable() {
    this.setState(
      {
        columnStatic: [{ name: "customerName", title: "Klient" }],
        columnsDynamic: [],
        columnBands: [],
        columns: [],
        tableColumnExtensions: [],
        percentColumns: []
      },
      () => {
        var i = 1;
        var j = 1;
        var k = 1;
        var l = 0;
        var dateArray = [];

        this.props.dataApi.map(dA => {
          dA.data.map(dat => {
            if (dateArray.indexOf(dat.date) > -1) {
              return;
            }
            dateArray.push(dat.date);

            this.setState(prevState => ({
              columnsDynamic: [
                ...prevState.columnsDynamic,
                { name: "ordersAmount" + i++, title: "Zamówienia" },
                { name: "earnings" + i++, title: "Obrót (brutto)" }
              ],

              columnBands: [
                ...prevState.columnBands,
                {
                  title: `${dat.date}`,
                  children: [
                    { columnName: "ordersAmount" + j++ },
                    { columnName: "earnings" + j++ }
                  ]
                }
              ],

              percentColumns: [
                ...prevState.percentColumns,
                `ordersAmount${l++ % 2 != 0 ? l : l++}`
              ],

              tableColumnExtensions: [
                ...prevState.tableColumnExtensions,
                {
                  columnName: "ordersAmount" + k++,
                  width: 90,
                  align: "right"
                },
                {
                  columnName: "earnings" + k++,
                  width: 150,
                  align: "right"
                }
              ]
            }));
          });
        });
      }
    );
  }

return (
  <Fragment>
      {this.props.isLoading ? (
          <div className={classes.loadingContainer}>
            <Loading />
          </div>
      ) : (
        <Fragment>
          <Paper>
            <Grid
              rows={dataApi}
              columns={columns.concat(columnStatic, columnsDynamic)}
            >
               ...
            </Grid>
          </Paper>
        </Fragment>
      )}
  </Fragment>
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in `componentDidUpdate` :

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (this.props.isLoading === false && prevProps.isLoading !== this.props.isLoading) {
    this.appendTable();
  }
}
```

Keeping it `PureComponent` would not be an issue, since `isLoading` is a primitive boolean prop, and hence the diff will trigger a component update.

Having said that, I would suggest not keeping the above information in a react state, as it can be derived from the props. You would just need to move the transformer logic into a method that can be invoked from the `render`. This would ensure single source of truth, which is `redux`'s core principle.

Comment: You're welcome. Have updated the answer with some more inputs.

Comment: can We add to this method my prevState? and in additional, when change my state (this.state.percentColumns), then run this method?

Please, look on my code. My method `appendTable()` always first set percentColumns to empty array and then set `percentColumns` values. I would like to display my table in render, when `percentColumns` always can be new. @Easwar

Comment: Yes. `componentDidUpdate` takes `prevState` as second parameter. Also please check `https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate` for complete API reference. You can always call the method `percentColumns` state changes from `componentDidUpdate`.